How to read the Flash Memory Partition Wise using ESP32-IDF Tools?
I am having the ESP32-Wroom Module and code has been into my FlashMemory I want to read the FlashMemory partition wise. Like I searched in google there are total 7 partitions

Reserved
Bootloader
Partition Table
NVS
Phy_init
Factory
Free Space.

So I want to have an CSV file or something in which I can have Partion name, Offset , Size ,Data this all columns should be there.

Here's an answer in the IoT section: https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/4288
